# Why does Notepad++ show weird indentation that doesn't exist?

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, notepad

Lately I've noticed some strange things happening since I updated Notepad++.

For example please see the weird indentation shown in the snippet below, for some reason the script open and close tags are shown in different positions even though Notepad++ confirms that they both start on the same column number.

[image]

I can copy and paste that code block in to another code editor, such as a plain Notepad and it appears correct.

[image]

How do I tell Notepad++ to stop messing with my files like this? :-)

Comment: Does the indentation contain a mixture of space and tab characters? Tabs can be shown with different lengths depending on the editor. If that's the case convert tabs to spaces to see consistent indentation across different editors.

Comment: I have Notepad++ set to convert tabs to spaces already.

Comment: A non visible utf character before <script> ?

Comment: Try ticking: Menu => Show => Show symbol => Show all characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `tab size` set to 1. (Even though you have set tabs to spaces checked).

Change the `tab size` to 2.

[image]

Here is what you had it.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: There are no tabs in the file.